# ${pageContext.request.contextPath} Working locally, but not remotely

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am in a strange situation where I found I currently have to use two different path-naming conventions depending on whether I am testing on localhost or my app is deployed to my domain.

Locally when I run my app, I access it here: `localhost:8080/MyApp/welcome` and on my domain, here: `mydomain.com/welcome`

On this welcome page (a JSP), I want to link to another page, say /welcome/foobar. If my link is of this style (note the pageContext prefix):

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome/foobar ... >
    <button type="submit">Admin Login</button>
</form>
```

Then locally, I will correctly be directed to `localhost:8080/MyApp/welcome/foobar`. The kicker is, that when I deploy and click this link on my domain, I am directed incorrectly to `http://welcome/foobar/`. I also receive the opposite result (incorrect locally, correct remotely) if I use a simple `<form action="/welcome/foobar" ... >` path.

Does anyone have a solution that would eliminate this mismatch? Also, I do not fully understand why this is happening, so bonus points to anyone who would also give me an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is to understand what is a `contextPath`and why it's used.

Let's take the example of your local URL.. `localhost:8080/MyApp/welcome`

What all information is available here..

`hostName` = localhost

`port` = 8080

`contextPath` = MyApp

Now take your real environment URL `mydomain.com/welcome`

`hostName` = mydomain.com

`port` = default i.e. 80

`contextPath` = `/`

So for your domain, the contextPath is just `/` which is how generally configured to shorten URL. The idea behind using the contextPath is generate relative LINKS for your jsp pages. It should better be used with `<anchor>` tags

If you just want a link to another page, you should use `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome/foobar">Submit </a>`

Comment: Unfortunately, using `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/welcome/foobar"` resolves to the path to be "//welcome/foobar" instead of "/welcome/foobar" even when nested in an anchor tag. Thank you for your dissection of the URL though, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Check what is your context path specified for your domain. I believe it's just a "/", that's why you see a double slash there. you should be using something like 
`${pageContext.request.contextPath}welcome/foobar`